# Assigning an Array to Another Array on the Heap C++

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, heap-memory, delete-operator

`T` is = to char
`counts_` is an array of integers stored on the heap
`values_` is an array of arrays on the heap

Problem arrives in the if statement, when I try to delete `tmpe` I get an error.  If I comment the delete statement out, the code runs but it just keeps pointing all of my pointers in `values_` to the same array.  The idea of the code is to create a new array containing the values of one of the selected `values_` arrays and then add one extra value to it.  Then re-assign it back to the spot in the `values_` array that I took it from.  The `tmpe` array is holding the correct values up to the point that I attempt to delete the pointer to it.  I get a Aborted (core dumped) error upon running my entire program.

```
if (initialized(n) == true)
{   
    T *tmpe = new T[counts_[n] + 1];
    for (size_type i = 0; i < counts_[n]; i++)
    {
        tmpe[i] = values_[n][i];
    }
    tmpe[counts_[n]] = val;
    delete [] values_[n];
    values_[n] = tmpe;
    delete [] tmpe;
    counts_[n]++;
}
else
{
    T *tmpd = new T[counts_[n] + 1];
    tmpd[counts_[n]] = val;
    delete [] values_[n];
    values_[n] = tmpd;
    delete [] tmpd;
    counts_[n]++;
}
```

Comment: vector vector vector vector vector

Comment: These 2 lines don't make sense together: `values_[n] = tmpe; delete [] tmpe;`

Comment: You're correct in not deleting it.  Think of it this way:  You're allocating a new memory block to hold the n+1 values, and filling it.  Then you delete the old memory block, and point values[n] to the newly created one.  Don't delete that new block!  By the way, @AlanStokes is correct.  Use a vector.  This whole block then looks like this: `values[n].push_back(val)`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you keep a pointer to `tmpe` but promptly deallocate the memory:

```
values_[n] = tmpe;
delete [] tmpe;
```

When the next iteration tries to access and/or delete `values_[n]`, it's a dangling pointer.

The same goes for `tmpd`.

If you used `std::vector`, you wouldn't have to worry about problems like this.

Comment: ok thanks, it was a long night and for some reason I couldn't think through this, and sorry this is for an assignment where I can't use std

Comment: "this is for an assignment where I can't use std" - this is ridiculous - try to get a different teacher if you can!

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to delete `tmpd` after you reassign `values_` to point to it. As soon as you reassign it, the memory is freed. What's happening is that you're trying to free something that doesn't exist.

Comment: Memory is not implicitly freed in C++.

Comment: @AlanStokes you're right. I didn't explain myself properly. What I meant to say was that when `values_[n] = tmpd`, `tmpd` can't be deleted anymore because it's not pointing to anything. That is how it works isn't it?

Comment: no, after the assignment both pointers are pointing at the same memory. You can `delete` either - but then you can no longer use both.

Comment: @AlanStokes so instead of using `delete` on the pointer that I don't want to use anymore I should just assign it to 0? So like for the example above it would be `values_[n] = tmpe; tmpe = 0;`?

Comment: that would work. Or just ignore it - when you exit the block the lifetime of `tmpe` ends and it harmlessly ceases to exist. (But what it pointed to is still there.)